# getSupportedPreviewSizes() for Motorola Xoom front camera (and other devices)

Tags: android, camera, size, preview

I have a few questions concerning supported preview sizes for devices with front cameras.  Not sure if I should ask here, but not really sure where else I would be able to find this answer.  Has to do with an app I'm creating.

My question is, what determines the supported preview sizes?  Is it the screen size or is it the camera?  Most android devices that have multiple cameras have a 1.3 MP front camera.   With that being said, are the supported preview sizes (from a getSupportedPreviewSizes() call) the same for cameras with the same MP?  The HTC Evo and HTC Flyer both have a 1.3MP front camera, but have very different screen sizes.  Are their supported preview sizes different?  Does it depend on the camera hardware, device screen size, or camera MP?

Follow on question: The motorola xoom is the only android device I'm aware of that has 2MP front camera.  I'm curious what it's supported preview sizes are.  If you have a Xoom, could you post the results of a getSupportedPreviewSizes() call on your front camera here?  It would be much appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

From experience with back facing cameras, the preview sizes are dependent on the hardware, and not related to the MP. What's more fun is that every manufacturer seems to report the sizes in a different way, sorted backwards or forwards by size, or just completely random (looking at you, Samsung!). 
I believe the Galaxy Tab 10.1 also has a 2 mp front facing camera. I have both it and the Xoom at home, so I can report on findings at a later time.

Comment: I can confirm that Samsung devices return a weird number on `getSupportedPreviewSizes()`